# Oracle Query: How to compare two column of different table having comma separated values

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql, split

How to compare two `prod_name` columns from different tables that have comma separated values?

These columns are having comma separated values in different order. To find a match, **all** values should match with other table `prod_name` column values.

In other words, the values may exist in different order in columns and that doesn't matter as long as all of the comma separated values are represented in both columns.

```
TABLE 1:
PRODUCT_ID                         PROD_NAME
================================================
1                                   O,G,E,H,R  
2                                   P,D,H,P,N
3                                   C,D,A,D,P
4                                   E,D,A,D,P


TABLE 2:
PRODUCT_ID  PROD_NAME
======================
5          R,O,G,E H
6          P,D,H,N,P
7          C,D,A,D
8          C,D,A,P,D
```

Expected Result:

```
1 matches with 5
2 matches with 6
3 matches with 8
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using `TRANSLATE` and `TRIM` function as following.

```
SQL> with t1 as
  2  (select 1 as product_id, 'O,G,E,H,R' as prod_name from dual union all
  3  select 2, 'P,D,H,P,N' from dual union all
  4  select 3, 'C,D,A,D,P' from dual union all
  5  select 4, 'E,D,A,D,P' from dual),
  6  t2 as
  7  (select 5 as product_id, 'R,O,G,E,H' as prod_name from dual union all
  8  select 6 as product_id, 'P,D,H,N,P' as prod_name from dual union all
  9  select 7 as product_id, 'C,D,A,D' as prod_name from dual union all
 10  select 8 as product_id, 'C,D,A,P,D' as prod_name from dual)
 11  SELECT
 12      T1.PRODUCT_ID,
 13      T2.PRODUCT_ID
 14  FROM
 15      T1
 16      JOIN T2 ON TRIM('#' FROM TRANSLATE(T1.PROD_NAME, T2.PROD_NAME, '#')) IS NULL;

PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_ID
---------- ----------
         1          5
         2          6
         3          8

SQL>
```

This query considers that your prod_name do not have `#` character in any of the value.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Brother Tej for spending time on this request! In spite of passing the values hardcoded, can we tweek the query to run the values dynamically from the table?

Comment: Offcourse, you just need to take query starting from line 11.

Comment: @Tejash . . . This is a clever solution if the codes really are single characters.  It does not generalize very well though.

Comment: Dear Tej, I am not getting the expected results. If the column of first table has 3 comma separated value then the column of 2nd table should also have the SAME set of 3 comma separated value.  The [COUNT + value] of comma separated values should be the same in both tables.

Comment: In Real, my values of column are like this below:                                                         PARACETAMOL,DEXTROMETHORPHAN HBR,GUAIFENESIN,PSEUDOEPHEDRINE HCL

Answer (score 1):

You have a very poor data structure.  However, Oracle has some powerful regular expression capabilities.  Assuming you have no duplicates, I think this works:

```
select t1.product_id, t2.product_id
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on regexp_count(t2.prod_name, replace(t1.prod_name, ',', '|')) =
        regexp_count(t1.prod_name, replace(t1.prod_name, ',', '|'));
```

Actually, this also does work for duplicates, but it does validate the counts of duplicates.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cb1dd3f8c2d334a97578ffd1fca1b59f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: There should be one to one match actually. l mean ALL comma separated values should match with other column comma separated values. This query is not correct.

Comment: @PramodKumar . . . Did you run the fiddle?  It does what you want.

Comment: No I have not tried yet. I am new to fiddle. When you say "run" , what are you trying me to do.   I want to clarify that the column values are like this:                                                                      PARACETAMOL,DEXTROMETHORPHAN HBR,GUAIFENESIN,PSEUDOEPHEDRINE HCL

Comment: @PramodKumar: "run the fiddle" means: click on the `here` link in Gorden's answer

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to not have comma separated values in a single attribute.  The First rule of Database Normalization says that a single attribute cannot hold multiple values, they must be decomposed into multiple tuples, with each tuple holding a single value of that attribute.